# Perform mathematical operations with the area under the curve from package ‘BSDA’

Tags: r, normal-distribution, probability-density

I have the following code to calculate the area under the curve:

```
library("BSDA")
normarea(0, 9.9, 10.5, 1.3)
```

My objective is to perform mathematical operations with the value of the "area under the curve", which in this case is 0.3222.

Specifically, I would like to be able to do this:

```
p<-normarea(0, 9.9, 10.5, 1.3)
q<-p*100
q
32.22
```

The problem is when I implement that code I get this error:

```
Error in p * 100 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

My question is: how can I extract the numerical component from the output of `normarea`?

I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: `X~Normal(mu=10.5, sigma=1.3)` is not valid R code. Where does `normarea` come from? Is this a user-defined function? From an R package?

Comment: I have addressed your point. Please share your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`normarea` just plots the area under the curve for a certain interval; it does not return the area, see `?normarea`.

However, executing `normarea` let's you see the source code of the function; the area is simply calculated using `pnorm` as

```
area <- pnorm(upper, m, sig) - pnorm(lower, m, sig)
```

So in your case, let's define a function to return the area

```
area_norm <- function(lower, upper, m, sig) {
    pnorm(upper, m, sig) - pnorm(lower, m, sig)
}
```

Then

```
area_norm(0, 9.9, 10.5 1.3);
#[1] 0.3222062
```

Comment: Thanks! This answers my question.

Comment: Great @Krantz, glad to help.